# What is the fastest way to get user specific data along with a query?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, performance

I'm working on a QnA app where I load the user-specific data such as whether or not the user voted a post, or following the user who wrote it. My current approach is the following-

```
SELECT tbl_answer.*, tbl_user.username, tbl_user.dp_62, tbl_personal_info.full_name, tbl_personal_info.tagline,
IFNULL(followers.following, 0) following,
IFNULL(voters.voted, 0) voted
FROM tbl_answer
LEFT JOIN tbl_user ON tbl_user.user_id = tbl_answer.user_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_personal_info ON tbl_personal_info.user_id = tbl_answer.user_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT answer_id, IF(a_vote_up = 1, 1, a_vote_down * -1) AS voted 
        FROM tbl_answer_vote
        WHERE user_id = $user_id //Retrieved from the token beforehand
    ) voters ON voters.answer_id = tbl_answer.answer_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT following_id, 1 AS following 
        FROM tbl_user_follow 
        WHERE follower_id = $user_id
    ) followers ON followers.following_id = tbl_answer.user_id
WHERE question_id = ?
ORDER BY selected DESC, 
under_review ASC, 
answer_up_vote DESC, 
answer_id ASC, 
answer_down_vote ASC
LIMIT 30
```

It doesn't seem to work as fast, takes over 4 seconds sometimes. The answer table has nearly a million entries.
**What is the general process of achieving this sort of result in minimal time?**
I'm using Laravel in my API backend if that's any factor to consider.

Thank you for any guidance.

Comment: The issue is that you only have single column indexes, while the where criteria would be served by a multi-column index. MySQL tries to make up for by using index merge, but that is not as efficient as using a single index.

Comment: The "general process" is to avoid unnecessary work. Why are subqueries used here? And what is your actual question? If you really ask for a "general process" I'm going to close vote as "needs more fokus".

Comment: I replaced the joins on votes, follows, and bookmarks with IF-EXISTS, which reduced the time to milliseconds. Should've tried that before posting here.

Comment: Before even thinking about that query, we need to know which column is in which table.  You must provide qualification and/or `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  It makes a _big_ difference for `WHERE  question_id = ?
        ORDER BY  selected DESC, under_review ASC, answer_up_vote DESC,
            answer_id ASC, answer_down_vote ASC
`

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question... the subqueries on the joins were the bottleneck here. Replacing them with IF-EXISTS improved the speed significantly, now takes an average of 300ms.

```
SELECT
    Q.*,
...
...
    IF(EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM tbl_question_vote WHERE user_id = 642 AND question_id = Q.question_id), 1, 0) voted,
    IF(EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM tbl_question_bookmark WHERE user_id = 642 AND question_id = Q.question_id), 1, 0) bookmarked,
    IF(EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM tbl_user_follow WHERE follower_id = 642 AND following_id = Q.user_id), 1, 0) following
LEFT JOIN tbl_user ON tbl_user.user_id = Q.user_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_personal_info ON tbl_personal_info.user_id = Q.user_id
WHERE
    under_review = 0 AND ads = 1
ORDER BY pinned DESC, prioritize DESC, question_id DESC
LIMIT 30
```

Answer (score 0):

A LEFT JOIN with a subquery is as good as a JOIN with an unindexed table. There are exceptions, where a subquery will generate an internal temporary table with an index. It's probably not the case here.

However - there is no need for a subquery in your case. All you need is a regular LEFT JOIN. Just include the condition on `$user_id` in the ON clause. Your query should look lik this:

```sql
SELECT ...
FROM tbl_answer
LEFT JOIN tbl_user ON tbl_user.user_id = tbl_answer.user_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_personal_info ON tbl_personal_info.user_id = tbl_answer.user_id

-- no subqueries necessary here
LEFT JOIN tbl_answer_vote
  ON  tbl_answer_vote.answer_id = tbl_answer.answer_id
  AND tbl_answer_vote.user_id   = $user_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_user_follow 
  ON  tbl_user_follow.following_id = tbl_answer.user_id
  AND tbl_user_follow.follower_id  = $user_id

WHERE ...
...
```

Comment: I did try this approach but didn't help with the speed, not sure why though it seems pretty straight forward.